# UnExpected Transform Error angular 16 using less, ERROR: Expected ")" to end URL token

Tags: angular, typescript

I dont understand where the missing parenthesis is. I assume its not this file at all. Any idea how to trouble shoot?

I also already turned off optimization

```
 "optimization": false
```

```
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
C:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/xxxx/xxxxxx/src/app/Components/home/home.component.less:508:38: ERROR: Expected ")" to end URL token

./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
C:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/xxxx/xxxxx/src/app/Components/home/home.component.less:508:38: ERROR: Expected ")" to end URL token
```

The File in Question

```
@import "../../../styles.less";
@import "../../../assets/StyleSheets/Tag.less";
@import "../../../assets/StyleSheets/Buttons.less";

@import "../../../assets/StyleSheets/Tabs.less";
@import "../../../assets/StyleSheets/Modal.less";

@import '../../../assets/StyleSheets/Colors.less';
@import '../../../assets/StyleSheets/Inputs.less';
@import '../../../assets/StyleSheets/Alerts.less';
```

angular version

```
Angular CLI: 16.2.0
Node: 20.5.1 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 9.8.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 16.2.1
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1602.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.2.0
@angular-devkit/core            16.2.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.2.0
@angular/cli                    16.2.0
@angular/http                   7.2.16
@schematics/angular             16.2.0
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.1.6
zone.js                         0.13.1
```

Comment: your style is incorrect. error is telling the location
home.component.less line 508

Comment: @SOisfullofMonkeys The home.component.less file is the "file in mention" it is 8 lines and all it does is import other files

Comment: that is not the file. what do you have in home component? can you show that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what happened for me was, a module wasnt compatible with the IVY engine. A developer on our team did npm update --force. And updated everything. How I trouble shooted it, I commented out every single .less file. And once all the .less files were empty, the npm package that didnt work was reveled. I deleted that packet, then went through the less files and uncommented their bodies one by one (while running ng server so it autobuild the app). All less files were uncommented and it built!

Comment: hi. can you elaborate more on commenting .less files. I also getting similar issue but its in styles.css file.An unhandled exception occurred: Transform failed with 1 error:
styles.d891275a951e6c1f.css:1:71: ERROR: Expected ")" to end URL token

Answer (score 0):

Well in my case it resulted in **ng build** *faluire* throwing unxpected tokenm **( closing error**.
I resolved this error by comming a variable and redeclaring it by enclosing the value of of **url** function in **double quotes**.

Here is the solution that worked for me.

```
 // --bs-btn-close-bg: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23000000'%3e%3cpath d='M.293.293a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 0L8 6.586 14.293.293a1 1 0 1 1 1.414 1.414L9.414 8l6.293 6.293a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.414L8 9.414l-6.293 6.293a1 1 0 0 1-1.414-1.414L6.586 8 .293 1.707a1 1 0 0 1 0-1.414z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
    --bs-btn-close-bg: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23000000'%3E%3Cpath d='M.293.293a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 0L8 6.586 14.293.293a1 1 0 1 1 1.414 1.414L9.414 8l6.293 6.293a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.414L8 9.414l-6.293 6.293a1 1 0 0 1-1.414-1.414L6.586 8 .293 1.707a1 1 0 0 1 0-1.414z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```